# Transforming a Riemann-Stieltjes integral related to the factorial

Tags: real-analysis, integration, factorial

I have been able to show that $$\log n! = \int_{1 + \epsilon}^n \log x \, d\lfloor x \rfloor$$

but I have not been successful trying to transform this Riemann-Stieltjes integral to an ordinary Riemann integral. The goal is to get rid of $d\lfloor x \rfloor$ via integration by parts, which should produce the terms $\frac{1}{2}\log n$ and $\int_1^n \left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}\right) \frac{dx}{x}$.

How exactly do these terms  arise?  I keep screwing up my computations. I've tried expressing this in a couple of different ways, but I don't seem to get the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: If you've shown that the integral is equal to $\log(n!)$, then you have evaluated the integral.

Comment: Showing that the integral is equal to $\log{n!}$ was given by an application of partial summation. I didn't really compute anything to make that conclusion.